# Call IEnumerable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a code to retrieve the records from a table:

```
var query = (from c in DBContext.MyTable where c.FacilityID == ID select c);
```

Then I want to list all records, I use the code below:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPages<T>(IQueryable<T> query, int pageSize)
{
    int pageNumber = 10;
    var page = GetPage(query, pageSize, pageNumber).ToList();
    while (page.Any())
    {
        yield return page;
        page = GetPage(query, pageSize, pageNumber).ToList();
    }
}

public IQueryable<T> GetPage<T>(IQueryable<T> query, int pageSize, int pageNumer)
{
    return query.Skip(pageNumer * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize);
}
```

I am not sure how to call `GetPages`?

My code is wrong.

```
IEnumerable<object> list = GetPages(query, 1000);
foreach (var result in list)
{
    string filePath = result.FilePath;
    string fileName = result.FileName;
    // log to output
}
```

**UPDATE:**
When I hover  var part of query.

> ```
>   System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<Something.Web.SharedObjects.MyTable>
> ```

I replace T with Something.Web.SharedObjects.MyTable. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming your `query` is an `IQueryable<FileResult>`, look at what the method is declared to return. You want something like:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<FileResult>> pages = GetPages(query, 1000);
foreach (IEnumerable<FileResult> page in pages)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of page!");
    foreach (var result in page)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result.FilePath, result.FileName);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End of page!");
}
```

It's important that you understand that what's returned is a sequence of *pages*, where each page is a sequence of *items*.

Comment: What is FileResult? my query returns rows from the table.

Comment: @Love: It's the `T` of your `IQueryable<T>` query. You didn't give us enough information about your *actual* types, so I had to make something up.

Comment: FilePath and FileName are string, can I replace "FileResult" with string or just use "object"?

Comment: @Love: No, `FilePath` and `FileName` are presumably properties of a type. What is that type? What is the element type of `DBContext.MyTable`?

Comment: I use entity framework code first. DBContext is entity framework context. MyTable is a table name. The table has many columns with different types such as int, bool and varchar.

Comment: @Love: I'm afraid I can't think of any more ways of asking you the question. One last try: if you hover over the `var` part of your declaration of `query`, what does it show you? (Seriously though, if you're finding it hard to grasp the meaning of my question - namely the type of your table - you may find that it's worth taking a step back and learning more about C# before doing more LINQ work.)

Comment: please see my updated. It is the table name. Is the table' name equivalent to its type?